# How can I get local timezone my messenger bot user?

Tags: timezone, timestamp, facebook-messenger-bot

I would like to either get the datetime of when the message was sent in user's local timezone or his/her local timezone.

How can I get that from in my bot? facebook gives the timestamp but I doubt if that timestamp is calculated based on the local timezone of the user.

Comment: I don't know who down voted this but before down voted I think it would be better stackoverflow to ask the person the reason why he downs vote. That can help also the one who posted the question. I really need a guidance on how can I get a true timezone of the my bot user.

Answer (score -3):

[The documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message) gives this example:

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"PAGE_ID"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "message":{
    "mid":"mid.1457764197618:41d102a3e1ae206a38",
    "text":"hello, world!",
    "quick_reply": {
      "payload": "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
    }
  }
}
```

The `timestamp` field in this example is a [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in terms of milliseconds.  Unix timestamps are *always* in terms of [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).  In other words, the epoch reference point is January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00.000 **UTC**.

Therefore, time zones are irrelevant to the message body.  You should simply convert from UTC to the desired time zone (probably the user's local time zone) when the message is displayed.

Comment: thanks, how can I get the timezone of the user(a reliable timezone everytime he/she uses the bot: in a way that if he was in Africa +03:00 and moves to america the timezone must change automatically) then? Converting from utc to user timezone will be dangerous operation since I don't know if facebook converts the datetime of sending from the user's timezone's to UTC or their just use UTC directly before sending that unix timestamp

Comment: An event occurs. The timestamp (in UTC) is captured.  There's nothing else to it.  Even if somehow Facebook started with a local time value and converted it (which would be absurd), the API is still giving you UTC-based results.  You can count on that.  There's nothing dangerous here.

Comment: Now if *you* are capturing input in terms of local time, then yes - certainly you will need to know what time zone that input is in.   Then you would convert from that to UTC before comparing.

Comment: This "answer" is drivel, it's all but beside the point completely. The question was HOW to get the user time zone, not whether it's relevant.